# How do i replace a line in a file?

Tags: c, file

My program is only work when the main function is short, when it's long it's stop working.

My program gets stuck at the line:

```
while (fgetc(f) != '\n');


void aktivpassziv(int sor, int aktiv, char rendszam[8], char helyzet)
{
int i = 0;
char tp;

FILE *f = fopen(".\\TAXI.txt", "r");
FILE *f2 = fopen(".\\temp.txt", "w");   

while ((tp = fgetc(f)) != EOF)
{
    if (tp == '\n') i++;

    if (i == sor)
    {
        fprintf(f2, "\n%s\t%d\t%c\n", rendszam, !aktiv, helyzet);

        while (fgetc(f) != '\n');
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(f2, "%c", tp);
    }


}
i = 0;

fclose(f);
fclose(f2);



}
```

My file containing number plates:
rendszam    aktiv   hely
ASD-123 0   A
ABC-123 0   B
HGK-187 1   F
FDD-333 1   K

Comment: Are you guaranteed to have a `'\n'` in your file everytime `i == sor`?

Comment: My file coantaning number plates:
rendszam aktiv hely
ASD-123 0 A
ABC-123 0 B
HSK-187 1 F
FDD-333 1 K

Comment: What is the character used as a delimiter between records in your file?  Is it a ***\n***?, or other?

Comment: It's '\n'. Exepct the last one what is EOF.

Comment: well, `EOF != '\n'`, so you are in an infinite loop in the case you get `EOF` not after a `\n` char.  If your file doesn't have a final `\n` in the last line, you'll get stuck in the while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
char tp;
```

use

```
int tp;
```

If `char` is an unsigned type in your platform, `tp` will never be equal to `EOF`.

And change the line

```
while (fgetc(f) != '\n')
```

to

```
while ( (tp = fgetc(f)) != '\n' && tp != EOF )
```

to avoid getting stuck with an infinite loop when you reach the end of the file.

In your posted code, you are using:

```
while (fgetc(f) != '\n');
i++;
```

It's not clear whether you meant to use that or you meant to use:

```
while (fgetc(f) != '\n')
   i++;
```

Use my suggestions appropriately.

Comment: It's duplicate the line what i want to rewrite. With any code with EOF, without EOF it stuck with an infinite loop.

Comment: @user3724530, you are welcome. Glad you got it to work.